# Getting hold of the rJava classloader

Tags: r, classloader, rjava

is there any clean way to get hold of the rJava classloader? Unfortunately I need it as I'm doing some dynamic object creations, etc.

I can use `rJava:::.env$.rJava.class.loader` but it's not exactly clean. Also since it uses private names new version of rJava can easily break my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `.jclassLoader()`

(PS: [stats-rosuda-devel](http://mailman.rz.uni-augsburg.de/mailman/listinfo/stats-rosuda-devel) is the mailing list for such questions)